# Angular6 map is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, observable, angular6

I am using angular6, when I write following code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
EditDetail(data) : Observable<Test[]> {
    let url = "http://www.example.com/api/getdetails";     
    return this.httpClient.get(url).map((response: Response) => {
    return <Test[]>response.json();
});
```

I am getting an error like :

```
this.httpClient.get(...).map is not a function
```

in browser console.

I have also tried by

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
```

And used

```
return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
map((response: Response) => <Test[]>response.json())
  );
```

But it shows error like

```
 this.httpClient.get(...).pipe is not a function
```

Comment: Angular 6 moved to RxJS 6, you need to migrate: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md.

Comment: I am using RXJS version 6

Answer (score 7):

Starting from ***RxJS 5.5*** you need to `pipe` `map` function.

```
return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
   map((response: Response) => <Test[]>response.json())
);
```

For more see [**Pipeable operators**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

Comment: I have tried but I am getting an error like :
this.httpClient.get(...).pipe is not a function

Comment: I have also added
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
But it's not working

Comment: There is something that is not correct in your code. `pipe` must be visible. Are you using RxJS 5.5 or higher ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution.

```
this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
    map(data => res)
).subscribe((data):any=>{
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: I have tried but I am getting an error like : this.httpClient.get(...).pipe is not a function

Comment: Are you using RXJS  version 6 if no then 

npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

Comment: Yes, I am using  RXJS version 6

Answer (score 1):

use pipe in order to use map. You need to use http client module in order use pipe function. Import this and initialize in constructor

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(map(data => res))
```

Comment: I have tried but I am getting an error like : this.httpClient.get(...).pipe is not a function

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to import operator map:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Second, you can use pipe(map()) like:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(map((response: Response) => {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 6 and rxjs 6.3.1 it works as described above. I also had some problems with this change in rxjs and created a small demo.

imports:

```
`import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators'
`
```

simple1 function with a httpclient-get. In the map function, some filtering is done. Return value is an observable :

```
`simple1(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').pipe(
      map((res:[any]) => {
        let newArray:[any] = <any>[] ;
        res.forEach( (e) => {
          if( e['title'][0] == 'a') {
              newArray.push( res[0])
          }
        })
        return newArray
      })
    )
  }`
```

Consume the observable:

```
`constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.simple1().subscribe(
      (response:HttpResponse<any>) => { console.log(response)},
      (error:HttpErrorResponse) => { console.log("error", error)},
      () => { console.log( 'finish')}
    )
  }`
```

[Complete demo code is here](https://github.com/rlassche/ng6_rxjs613_pipe_and_map)